# Angular 2 Unit Testing prepare mocking to share in components

Tags: unit-testing, angular, mocking

I'm doing unit test in my Angular2 application and very new to angular2 test framework.

I have 2 components and calling same method from a service.

Firstly, I need to import the service and model to create the mock

```ts
import { MyService } from '../../shared/my.service';
import { MyModel } from '../../shared/my.model';
```

Secondly, arrange the model and service to mock

```ts
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  const mockMyModel: MyModel[] = [];
  const mockMyService = {
    sameMethod: () => Observable.of(mockMyModel),
  };
```

Finally, mock the service

```ts
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent],
    })
    .overrideComponent(MyComponent, {
      set: {
        providers: [
          { provide: MyService , useValue: mockMyService },
        ],
      },
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

I need to do the same thing again for my another component.

- Option 1: is there any way to globally share the preparation for mock
  e.g. `{ provide: MyService , useValue: global.mockMyService }`
- Option 2: is it possible to have 'ServiceTestingModule' such as 'RouterTestingModule' just to mock a service.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 definitely can be used

```ts
myMockProvider = { provide: MyService , useValue: mockMyService };

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent],
    })
    .overrideComponent(MyComponent, {
      set: {
        providers: [myMockProvider],
      },
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

`myMockProvider` can also be a list of providers. Nested lists are resolved/flattened by `providers: [...]` automatically.